# How to assign name to every circle in a Venn diagram using R (Venndiagram package)

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I would assign a name for every circle in a Venn diagram. I have tried to change options in category but seems this is the only set I can use. I attach my code, please where is the wrong part?

```
         goterm3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
         goterm2 =c(2,2,3,4,3,5)
        goterm1=c(4,5,3,2,4,3,2,4)
      int12 = intersect(goterm1, goterm2)
    int13 = intersect(goterm1, goterm3)
    int23 = intersect(goterm2, goterm3) 
    intall = intersect(int12, goterm3)
    require(VennDiagram)

      venn.plot =  draw.triple.venn(length(goterm1), length(goterm2), length(goterm3),
       length(int12), length(int23), length(int13),length(intall),
 category = rep("ORG1, ORG2,Org",3) ,rotation = 1, reverse = FALSE, euler.d =    FALSE,
      scaled = FALSE, lwd = rep(2, 3), lty = rep("solid", 3),
      col = rep("black", 3), fill = c("blue", "red", "green"),
      alpha = rep(0.5, 3),
     label.col = rep("black", 7), cex = rep(1, 7), fontface = rep("plain", 7),
      fontfamily = rep("serif", 7), cat.pos = c(0, 0, 180),
      cat.dist = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.025), cat.col = rep("black", 3),
      cat.cex = rep(1, 3), cat.fontface = rep("plain", 3),
      cat.fontfamily = rep("serif", 3),
      cat.just = list(c(0.5, 1), c(0.5, 1), c(0.5, 0)), cat.default.pos = "outer",
      cat.prompts = FALSE, rotation.degree = 0, rotation.centre = c(0.5, 0.5),
      ind = TRUE, sep.dist = 0.05, offset = 0)
```

Comment: If your prior Venn diagram question was answered, you should click the checkmark to the best answer. In this question you should add the code that will create "goterm" objects. And you should put in a `library()` command that will load whatever package you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I have done it in another part of the code that I`ve not posted. The problem should be in rep(blabla),but i-ve not still found the solution. This is the function just for the diagram, obviously I have created earlier

Comment: I didn't doubt that you had done it. I was asking for a reproducible example.

Comment: I have just edit the question. I hope you could help me, thank's!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get and it does have the same labels as your categories (after I unmangled the string values for the categories:

```
  category = c("ORG1", "ORG2","Org") # no rep needed and proper quotes
```

[image]